# PHP: Split cookie value and count parts

Tags: php, cookies, split, explode

I am a PHP beginner and hope someone here can help me with this.

I have a string that looks like the following example where the separator is an underscore and the length of the string can vary. 
The three digit numbers are IDs and the numbers in brackets are counts.

**Example:** `101(2)_102(3)_103(5)`

I am looking for a way to split this in a way that I can **access each ID and each count** in order to use them for further calculations etc. 
I tried using explode but couldn't get this to work.

**My attempt:**

```
print_r(explode("_", $_COOKIE['myCookieName']));
```

I assume I need to create an array here.

**Expected output (example):** `Total IDs: 3, total count: 10`

Can someone tell me how to achieve this ?

Many thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to extract the `id` and `count` values and then [`count`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) and [`sum`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) them:

```
$cookie = '101(2)_102(3)_103(5)';
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|_)([^(]+)\((\d+)\)(?=_|$)/', $cookie, $matches);
$ids = $matches[1];
$counts = $matches[2];
echo "Total IDs: " . count($ids) . ", total count: " . array_sum($counts);
```

Output:

```
Total IDs: 3, total count: 10
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5Qr0B)

Note that you may find it more useful to have an array of counts indexed by the `id` values, for which you can use [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) on the output of `preg_match_all`:

```
$counts = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
echo "Total IDs: " . count($counts) . ", total count: " . array_sum($counts). PHP_EOL;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/qFPJr)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nick ! This is perfect and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler version that should work as well:

```
$cookie = '101(2)_102(3)_103(5)';
preg_match_all('/\((\d+)\)/', $cookie, $matches);
[, $counts] = $matches;
echo 'Total IDs: ', count($counts), ', total count: ', array_sum($counts);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/PQ14O**

Comment: Yeah - if OP doesn't care about `id` values this is definitely simpler. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot for this as well. I do need the ID values as well but this just came up after I had submitted my post already so both solutions helped me a lot.