# PHP: List and group value pairs from string

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, preg-match, explode

I use the following lines to count values within a string which works fine so far. 
How can I **list the values for each value pair** as in the example below **if the length of my string and contained values vary** ?

**My PHP (so far):**

```
$str= '101(2)_102(3)_103(5)';
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|_)([^(]+)\((\d+)\)(?=_|$)/', $str, $matches);
$ids = $matches[1];
$counts = $matches[2];
```

**Expected output (example):**

```
id1: 101, count1: 2
id2: 102, count2: 3
id3: 103, count3: 5
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the code from the second part of my answer to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359439/php-split-cookie-value-and-count-parts), you can just use a `foreach` loop over the result array:

```
$cookie = '101(2)_102(3)_103(5)';
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|_)([^(]+)\((\d+)\)(?=_|$)/', $cookie, $matches);
$counts = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
$i = 1;
foreach ($counts as $id => $count) {
    echo "id$i: $id, count$i: $count\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Output:

```
id1: 101, count1: 2
id2: 102, count2: 3
id3: 103, count3: 5
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vrGZf)